# Inaccurate Battery Consumption Metrics: Is This Behavior Normal?

Tags: battery, battery-life, battery-history

I own a **OnePlus6** running **OxygenOS 9.0.9**. I noticed that lately my battery doesn't last as long as it used to. I used the Battery Monitor app to check if there's anything suspicious. This is what I noticed:

[image]

In this screenshot my battery is at 88% (12% consumed), yet, the app consumption sums up to 8% as opposed to the 12% that is actually consumed.

Is this behavior normal? Is the remaining 4% being consumed by the OS or is there some rogue app that's consuming my battery?

Comment: You may have dozens of apps that have usage of below 1% -> rounded down to 0% and therefore not displayed. Anyway the usage stats are always just an estimation.

Comment: Tap on that three dots line > show full device usage. Then see how much difference is there.